# Pause/Resume another thread

Tags: c, pthreads

I know mutex can be an implementation, however I'm wondering there would be a way to pause/resume another thread as in video-playback. This approach is easier to program when the other running thread is complex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606400/how-to-sleep-or-pause-a-pthread-in-c-on-linux may help you

Comment: It may be easier to program, but it is harder to get correct.  Much harder.  Nearly impossible, in fact...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [SIGTSTP](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Job-Control-Signals.html), a signal for pausing processes, which you could use if you have two processes, but signals have several drawbacks so I wouldn't recommend using them. For a controlled, stable method you'd have to do it yourself using a mutex, where user pausing the playback leads to locking the mutex, and the thread doing the playback tries to lock the mutex . Like this:

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex;

/* UI thread */
void g(void)
{
    while(1) {
        get_input();
        if(user_wants_to_pause)
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        else if(user_wants_to_resume)
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

/* rendering thread */
void f(void)
{
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        /* if we get here, the user hasn't paused */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        render_next_frame();
    }
}
```

If you need more communication between the two threads you could use the standard IPC mechanisms like pipes - you could then implement pausing and resuming based on that.