# C++ pthread_t - How to stop a pthread_t for a period of time

Tags: c++, timer, pthreads

How is it possible to stop a pthread_t for a period of time? And I mean no using of the sleep function ;)

Comment: I need any possibility. It doesnt care what kind of possibility but just no sleep.

Comment: @TobiWeißhaar: Why not sleep?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sleep or pause a PThread in c on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606400/how-to-sleep-or-pause-a-pthread-in-c-on-linux)

Comment: please be more specific with the task you are trying to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pthread_cond_wait` (or `pthread_cond_timedwait`, but probably not) to block the thread. You'll need a predicate -- a variable that holds a value that indicates whether the thread should go or stop. And you'll need a mutex to protect the predicate and condition variable. Another thread can then unblock the thread by taking the mutex, changing the predicate, signalling the condition variable, and releasing the mutex.

However, generally, you just shouldn't do this. If there's something to do, you should let the thread do it. If there's nothing to do, the thread should be coded to either terminate or wait for work. If you have to force this with specific code, it's likely that you're doing something wrong in the first place.

The thread should be coded to do all, and only, what you want it to do. You shouldn't need to "push it around" from the outside except in truly unusual situations.

Answer (score 1):

If your threads implementation library supports it, you can use `pthread_suspend` and `pthread_continue` from main thread or another one using any kind of "sleeping time counting".

See man pages about normal uses.

Answer (score 0):

you could wait on the thread handle itself with a timeout ... A thread handle is signalled once the thread terminates, so it will time out while running.

Answer (score 0):

your question is rather unspecific. There are some possible approaches, but that depends on what you want to achieve.
Do you want to interrupt the thread? do you want to have a point where the thread 'blocks' execution until a certain criterion is met?
Who should be able to stop your thread? who should be able to restart its operation?

Some possibilities include:

- thread suspensions: [pthread_suspend](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3t/pthread_suspend/)
- synchronisation: [mutexes](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock), [semaphores](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html), [spinlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock), [pause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/pause.htm)/[alarm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/alarm.htm)
- ...

Answer (score -1):

Hoi,

how exact does it need to be? You could consider starting another thread as soon as the first thread is stopped. This "new" thread runs for a specific time and then restarts thread number one.
If the stop is just needed once, you can add a counter.

If you need this all repeatedly, you could also consider a periodic time triggered pthread.

Regards,
G.