# how can I pause/stop threads on linux to run another thread of top priority

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11, embedded

I will have a **linux service** that waits messages from a central and let the tasks do that are ordered by those messages. I think to do is I need to create a new **thread**.

Moreover, one task would have an absolute priority compared to others and when the order for that task comes, I need to accomplish it as soon as possible. Also, since all these stuff is on embedded system and resources are restricted, I thought I need to pause all other threads that were created.

I imagine that I need some thing similar as here:

[How to sleep or pause a PThread in c on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606400/how-to-sleep-or-pause-a-pthread-in-c-on-linux)

But the question is not duplicate. I do not have exact point to pause threads. I need to pause them wherever possible, and continue when the prioritized task is finished.

And here it suggests a way that seems obsolete and also I could use **std::thread**.

[How to pause a pthread ANY TIME I want?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397068/how-to-pause-a-pthread-any-time-i-want)

- How could I achieve prioritize one task?
- (Maybe before that) To do tasks, do I need to design some thing like "Thread manager", or there could be simpler thoughts?

**Note:** I have used the word "task" as it is, not as a technical term.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html

Comment: I think you are thinking about the wrong approach. You will have to sync these threads and use a mutex on the shared resources. Better might be to use a priority queue for your messages and a single worker thread. Anything else quickly becomes a nightmare of race-conditions, resp. locking to avoid them.

Comment: @Olaf but why not benefit from multithreading and use a single worker thread?

Comment: You might have missed my point. However, after your comment, it seems to be less clear whatr you actually want.